# pyspark Spark 2.1.1 s3n Input path does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

On the console

```
aws s3 cp s3://com.philadelphia-reflections.php/.htaccess htaccess
```

does what is expected: it downloads the text file

in pyspark, however,

```
sc.hadoopFile(path = 's3n://com.philadelphia-reflections.php/.htaccess', 
              conf = {
                      'fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId': '...',
                      'fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey': '...',
                    },
              inputFormatClass = "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat" , 
              keyClass = "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
              valueClass = "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"
             )
```

produces the following, the essential part of which is "`Input path does not exist: s3n://com.philadelphia-reflections.php/.htaccess`"

s3://...  produces "`java.io.IOException: /.htaccess doesn't exist`"
s3a://... produces "`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: s3a://com.philadelphia-reflections.php/.htaccess`"

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-67f3549c21f9> in <module>()
      6               inputFormatClass = "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat" ,
      7               keyClass = "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
----> 8               valueClass = "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"
      9              )

/home/george/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py in hadoopFile(self, path, inputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter, conf, batchSize)
    706         jrdd = self._jvm.PythonRDD.hadoopFile(self._jsc, path, inputFormatClass, keyClass,
    707                                               valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter,
--> 708                                               jconf, batchSize)
    709         return RDD(jrdd, self)
    710 

/home/george/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/george/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/george/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.hadoopFile.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: s3n://com.philadelphia-reflections.php/.htaccess
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1333)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1327)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$.pairRDDToPython(SerDeUtil.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.hadoopFile(PythonRDD.scala:625)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.hadoopFile(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

is `com.philadelphia-reflections.php` the name of your bucket? If so, it doesn't work with s3n or s3a clients, which require a bucket to have a simple hostname, such as `philadelphia-reflections`

Create a bucket with a simple "hostname" style bucket name, and copy the data there for use.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I created the very simple bucket ```philadelphiareflections``` and the result is the same

Comment: Ok. Try something else. See if you can use s3a://landsat-pds/scene_list.gz as a source of data; its a gzipped CSV file. Amazon serve that up to all; we use it to test things like Spark S3A integration. If you can use that as a source input then we know its a path problem. Where the next thing I'd check is "can you use a file with the prefix "." as a source?" . It's possible both .* and _* get skipped

Comment: I think my problem is with hidden files: those prefixed by a period. I can download "regular" files, but all prefixed with a period fail.

Comment: well, that's your problem I'm afraid. They'll be considered "hidden" and  not showing in listings of directories, that being how Spark decides what files to process. Possibly fixable by playing with custom PathFilters &c, simplest just to rename the file.